# Calculating growth rates on specific level of multilevel index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that I want to use to calculate the average quarterly growth rate, broken down by each year in the dataset.

Right now I have a dataframe with a multi-level grouping, and I'd like to apply the `gmean` function from `scipy.stats` to each year within the dataset.

The code I use to get the quarterly growth rates looks like this:

```
df.groupby(df.index.year).resample('Q')['Sales'].sum() / df.groupby(df.index.year).resample('Q')['Sales'].sum().shift(1)
```

Which gives me this as a result:

[image]

So basically I want the geometric mean of (1.162409, 1.659756, 1.250600) for 2014, and the other quarterly growth rates for every other year.

Instinctively, I want to do something like this:

```
(df.groupby(df.index.year).resample('Q')['Sales'].sum() / df.groupby(df.index.year).resample('Q')['Sales'].sum().shift(1)).apply(gmean, level=0)
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: `(df.groupby(df.index.year).resample('Q')['Sales'].sum() / df.groupby(df.index.year).resample('Q')['Sales'].sum().shift(1)).groupby(level=0).mean()`?

Comment: or reset_index an then groupby by years

Comment: @ansev that would be using the arithmetic mean, would it not?  In this case I need to apply a function that's more customized than one of the stock reducers in Pandas.

Comment: then `apply(gmean)` instead `.mean`

Comment: `gmean` basically is just `prod()**(1/period)`. You can just use `groupby().prod()` and raise the series to the coresponding power.

Comment: On another note, please do include sample data and expected output.

Comment: and that worked.  Thank you.  In this case, is there a better way than using two groupby's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what your data looks like so I'm gonna make some random sample data:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2014-01-01', '2017-12-31')
n = 5000

np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Order Date': np.random.choice(dates, n),
    'Sales': np.random.uniform(1, 100, n)
})

  Order Date      Sales
0 2016-11-27  82.458720
1 2014-08-24  66.790309
2 2017-01-01  75.387001
3 2016-06-24   9.272712
4 2015-12-17  48.278467
```

And the code:

```
# Total sales per quarter
q = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Order Date', freq='Q'))['Sales'].sum()

# Q-over-Q growth rate
q = (q / q.shift()).fillna(1)

# Y-over-Y growth rate
from scipy.stats import gmean
y = q.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Y')).agg(gmean) - 1
y.index = y.index.year
y.index.name = 'Year'

y.to_frame('Avg. Quarterly Growth').style.format('{:.1%}')
```

Result:

```
        Avg. Quarterly Growth
Year                    
2014                    -4.1%
2015                    -0.7%
2016                     3.5%
2017                    -1.1%
```

Comment: Question:  Is there an advantage to using `pd.Grouper` over `df.resample()` like I did in my original example?

Comment: It looks cleaner and easier to read to me -- you don't have to change the index and whatnot. I have not investigated the performance angle but will be surprised if there are big differences between the 2 approaches